# Visual Studio cannot recognize that I added a new setting to app.config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I added a new setting called `SQLServerNames` to my app.config file that I will use for a combo box in my application but when I go to my code-behind to try to access it with `Properties.Settings.Default`, I can only see the other settings that were added previously. When I type in `SQLServerNames`, Visual Studio says that Settings does not contain a definition for it. But when I go to the UI in Setting.Settings that displays all the settings, it is listed there. How can I get it to recognize that it is there?
Here is the setting that I have added to my app.config file:

```xml
<setting name="SQLServerNames" serializeAs="String"><value>option1,option2,option3</value></setting>``
```

And here is the error that I am getting:

> Error  CS1061  'Settings' does not contain a definition for 'SQLServerNames' and no accessible extension method 'SQLServerNames' accepting a first argument of type 'Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thank you.

Comment: did you re-compile your app after adding?

Comment: @T.S. I tried that and I also restarted my application but it seems to still be throwing an error.

Comment: seem VS is just stuck. Nothing else. Remove your settings, clean solution, compile, Then add again,